# Forge returning NoSuchMethodExcepton on Entity#getName()

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm attempting to write a (very simple) Forge mod that watches for and alerts on chicken spawns, but the code refuses to work. Instead, it throws a `NoSuchMethodException` when I attempt to read the entity name.

My code is as follows:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void OnEntityJoinWorld(EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
    if (!(event.getEntity() instanceof EntityChicken)) {
        return;
    }

    Entity chicken = event.getEntity();

    String message = "Chicken named " + chicken.getName() + " spawned at " + chicken.posX
                                                          + "," + chicken.posY
                                                          + "," + chicken.posZ
                                                          + ".";

    Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.addChatMessage(new TextComponentString(message));
    LOGGER.info(message);
}
```

The specific error is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.entity.Entity.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Both the Forge and Minecraft versions being used are the same, so either I'm overlooking something very simple, or this just isn't how I'm supposed to do what I'm trying to do. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to compile your project using the Gradle `build` option as opposed to the `jar` option.

When using just `jar`, Gradle will not re-obfuscate all of Minecraft's code. In turn, this will cause it (obviously) not to be able to find the non-obfuscated methods and names.

Answer (score 0):

Shouln't you use:
EntityChicken chicken = event.getEntity();
And then import EntityChicken?

EDIT:
your error is becouse when you do chicken.getName(), it wants to get the name of event.getEntity() and the type of event.getEntity() is set to Entity which gives the error. What you should do is change the type of event.getEntity() to EntityChicken, as said above